# Pyinstaller failed to import scipy.signals

Tags: python, scipy, python-import, pyinstaller

Try to create exe file from python scipt with imported module scipy.signals. Pyinstaller perform well with no errors but new .exe file gives me error like :

```
Failed to decode wchar_t from UTF-8
MultiByteToWideChar: ╬сырёЄ№ фрээ√ї, яхЁхфрээр  яю ёшёЄхьэюьє т√чютє, ёыш°ъюь ьрыр.
share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.cache\terser-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\2e\ba\cfce62ec1f408830c0335f2b46219d58ee5b068473e7328690e542d2f92f2058865c600d845a2e404e282645529eb0322aa4429a84e189eb6b58c1b97c1a could not be extracted!
```

BUT when I change row in a py file from

```
from scipy imports signals
```

to

```
import scipy
```

exec file perform great.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when packaging up an script that used `xarray`. The solution was to find out which package was importing `jupyter`, and add it to the list of *excluded-modules*. In my case, I *excluded* `dask`, but in your case things will be different.

I would rerun your pyinstaller command with `--log-level DEBUG` in order to get some more logging information, then take a look at the log files generated in the *build/* directory. If you have *graphviz*, or know how to work with *graphs*, then you can analyze the *.dot* file to learn about the packages that install *jupyter/IPython*. If you don't know how to use *graphviz*, no problem, just open up the html file in a browser. This file shows all of the packages imported by your script, and all of the packages that those packages import, and are imported by, etc. Beware, this is a really complex web of *package A imports ...* and *package A is imported by ...*, so don't get lost in the details.

The goal here is to find the *path* of imports that leads from your script to *IPython/jupyter* that is leading to this issue. You want to stop this *path* wherever seems logical for your script. In your case, many of the `scipy` subpackages import `matplotlib.pyplot`, which imports `IPython`, which imports things which eventually import `jupyter_client`. You want to sever this path from your script to *jupyter/IPython* as early as you can by *excluding* one of the packages. The package you decide to *exclude* will depend on your app.

The easiest way to get rid of this error would be to sever this *path* from your script to `jupyter` by *excluding* `matplotlib`. However, if you use matplotlib in your script to generate plots, then you can't do that. You would have to pick a package that is more downstream. Ultimately you could exclude `IPython`, and that should do the trick. Take a look at the pyinstaller documentation for how to use the `--exclude-module` argument:

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

Or this stackoverflow question which has some more info:

[How to remove/exclude modules and files from pyInstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034434/how-to-remove-exclude-modules-and-files-from-pyinstaller)

On a side note, you should start getting comfortable *excluding* unnecessary packages since this can **drastically** decrease the size of your bundled app and improve performance.