# Pyinstaller Failed to extract jupyter/terser: file not found

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, jupyter-lab, file-not-found

When trying to run the `.exe` file built with Pyinstaller, I get the error:

```
Failed to extract
share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.cache\terser-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\2e\ba\cfce62ec1f408830c0335f2b46219d58ee5b068473e7328690e542d2f92f2058865c600d845a2e404e282645529eb0322aa4429a84e189eb6b58c1b97c1a could not be extracted!
fopen: No such file or directory
```

My pyinstaller command is
`pyinstaller --name=app ERP/app.py --add-data="ERP/templates;templates" --add-data="ERP/static;static" --add-data="ERP/recursos;recursos" --add-data="ERP/querys;querys" --add-binary="C:/Users/Germain/Proyecto 4/venv/Lib/site-packages/xgboost/lib/xgboost.dll;." --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._typedefs" --exclude-module=IPython --exclude-module=matplotlib --exclude-module=jupyterlab --exclude-module=Tkinter --exclude-module=PyQt5 --exclude-module=PyQt4 --exclude-module=wxPython --exclude-module=Pillow --exclude-module=Pygame --exclude-module=pywin32 --noupx --upx-exclude="*\\numpy\\*" --debug=all`

I am excluding those packages because of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555903/pyinstaller-failed-to-decode-wchar-t-from-utf-8-fopen-no-such-file-or-direct)
, but it did not seem to work.

My `app.py` file is a flask app that is using the modules

- flaskext
- flask
- sklearn
- xgboost
- datetime
- json
- os
- pandas
- numpy
- statsmodels

I have already tried running the pyinstaller command as Admin, creating a venv for the app, runing it from another pc with a new conda install.

Comment: have you tried using pip instead of conda?