# Pyinstaller - Exclude files from final executable

Tags: python, linux, windows, pyinstaller

I am developing an cross platform application which ships additional binary files from source directory for linux and windows. Right now I am using following script in my *.spec file to include all binaries from the source directory.

```
##### include mydir in distribution #######
def extra_datas(mydir):
    def rec_glob(p, files):
        import os
        import glob
        for d in glob.glob(p):
            if os.path.isfile(d):
                files.append(d)
            rec_glob("%s/*" % d, files)
    files = []
    rec_glob("%s/*" % mydir, files)
    extra_datas = []
    for f in files:
        extra_datas.append((f, f, 'DATA'))

    return extra_datas
###########################################

# append the 'data' dir
a.datas += extra_datas('data')
```

All works well. Now the issue is that when i create binay from windows, all additional binaries of linux also shiped in the final executable. This makes the final stand alone executable bigger in size.

**Is there a way to tell pyinstaller to execlude certain files/ binarries from source directory.** Also **is it possible to execlude certain *.so/ *.dll which are really not required in the final executable?**

I use the following for development:-

Python 2.7

Pyinstaller 2.1

Debian 7 for linux

Windows 7 for Win

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure just add a list of files to exclude

```
def extra_datas(mydir,exclude=[]):
    def rec_glob(p, files):
        import os
        import glob
        for d in glob.glob(p):
            if os.path.isfile(d):
                files.append(d)
            rec_glob("%s/*" % d, files)
    files = []
    rec_glob("%s/*" % mydir, files)
    return [(f, f, 'DATA') for f om files if f not in exclude]

a.datas += extra_datas(some_dir,["something.txt","something.exe",...])
```

as for DLL's im pretty sure there is an explicit exlude to exclude dll's that would normally automagically be included

[edit] see this answer wrt excluding dll's https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595149/541038

Comment: Thank you for the script. It worked. But with little modification. Like this:-  `a.datas += extra_datas(some_dir,["path/to/something.txt","path/to/something.exe",...])`