# PyInstaller 2.1 import custom package

Tags: python, hook, pyinstaller

I have a script I'm trying to compile with PyInstaller (2.1) using Python 2.7

The script uses a custom package I've written called 'auto_common'

In the script I import it by using

```
sys.path.append(path_to_package)
```

The project folders look like this:

```
Automation/                  Top level project
    Proj1/
        script1.py           This is the script I want to compile
        myspec.spec          Spec file for the script
    Packages/
        auto_common/
            __init__.py      Init module of the package (empty)
            ...              More modules here
```

In the PyInstaller log file I get the following warning:

```
W: no module named auto_common (top-level import by __main__)
```

How do I create a hook which will include the package (using sys.path.append for example)?

I tried adding the path of the package to 'pathex' in the spec file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using "-p" when compiling (or when building a spec file) will add additional paths to python's path.

```
pyinstaller -p any_path/Automation/Packages script1.py
```

This mimics the behavior of sys.path.append().

Thanks to the guys at PyInstaller for the solution:

[sys.path.append does not work when compiling with PyInstaller 2.1](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/903)

Comment: Is it also possible to remove a path from python path?

Comment: @LLaP
Yes you can.
You can read more here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890159/python-excluding-modules-pyinstaller/17595149#17595149

Comment: How can I use `-p path_of_the_package` directly inside `script.spec` file?

Comment: Is this not the purpose of the `setup()` function's `packages=["auto_common"]` configuration?