# Pyinstaller automatically includes unneeded modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a .exe from a very simple script that I have written. The script only include glob and pandas. But pyinstaller is including matplotlib,numpy,scipy,qt4,ipython, and a bunch of other stuff. The .exe won't run because there is an error with matplotlib, but I don't even need matplotlib. What am I doing wrong to make pyinstaller not recognize that only glob and pandas are needed?

I have manually excluded scipy,matplotlib,PyQt4,and iPython and the .exe is still 160mb!

P.S. I'm doing this in winpython with python 3.4.

Edit: 
With a little further testing I have narrowed this down to Pandas. Even a script that only consists of:

```
import pandas
```

will create a dist folder that is 460MB or a single file .exe that is 182MB. What is the easiest way that I can find out which modules are being imported so that I can properly exclude all of them?

Edit2:
I have tried making a hook-pandas.py file that contains:

```
excludedhooks=['scipy','matplotlib','PIL','cython','PyQt4','zmq']
```

The console output indicates that imports are being removed due to the hook file, but tons of files from these modules still end up in the dist folder.

I have also tried excluding these modules in the .spec file as well as in the console using --exclude-module but the files from those modules still show up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890159/python-excluding-modules-pyinstaller/17595149#17595149 have a look

Comment: So i need to go through and manually exclude everything that I don't need? Why would it assume that I was all those modules included?

Comment: Well I do not know that, but I guess the answer is written in the PyInstaller's official manual.

Comment: Some of that stuff is definitely necessary. Pandas is built upon NumPy, so you'll definitely need NumPy.

Comment: Wild guess, but don't you have some unnecessary big files(e.g. binaries) in your app folder? PyInstaller may take those into the package too. What's included is in console output afaik.

Comment: Bloat is even worse under Anaconda.  [Related Git discussion here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1694).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this really counts as a solutions. But by ignoring winpython all together and using a standard installation of python that only had pip installs of pyinstaller and pandas added to it I was easily able generate a functional .exe that was 18MB. I guess it had something to do with winpython.

Answer (score 2):

Pyinstaller may have figured those dependencies from your current ones. If you're sure, use `--exclude-module` flag to list all the modules you want to exclude.

http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#general-options