# PyInstaller: cannot exclude a module

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have compiled the exe of a .py file but the problem is that it is 200mb+
I would like to remove useless packages (for instance `scipy` that I am not using).

Still I have not clear the proper syntax of PyInstaller.

Let's start from the beginning...usually I do on cmd:

```
cd myFolder
C:\Python27\Scripts\Pyinstaller.exe MyFile.py
```

and it gives me the exe file in the dist folder.

If I want to set some configuration which is the proper way?

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\Pyinstaller.exe MyFile.py Config.py
```

or

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\Pyinstaller.exe Config.py
```

because online I found both of them but I could not distinguish.

If it is the last one I tried to run:

```
lock_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['Main.py'],
     pathex=['C:\Users\myname\Desktop\myFolder'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=None,
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=None,
     runtime_hooks=None,
     excludes=None,
     cipher=block_cipher)
a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not x[0].startswith("scipy")]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
     cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz)
coll = COLLECT(exe)
```

But it does not work. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is that you use a virtual env containing only the required modules. It is a better development practice.

Also, you can use `--exclude-module` flag to list all the modules you want to exclude. ([Pyinstaller automatically includes unneeded modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678903/pyinstaller-automatically-includes-unneeded-modules))

Comment: Thanks do you have a good guide for what concerns point 1 and  the command --exclude-module is to be included in cmd? There is no way to fix it with thecode I have posted? Thanks a lot

Comment: you can see the answer for that in here: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html