# Control PyInstaller build size including pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I want to build single-file executable on Windows 10 that uses pandas.  Following is the totality of my single-file script `TrivialTest.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(456)
j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C'] for b in pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='W')]
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(j, names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15), i, columns=['Vals'])
df.to_csv('Test.csv')
```

Initial PyInstaller builds, whether `--onefile` or `--onedir`, produce `.exe` files approaching 300MB in size.

Note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36683457/2662901) claims that running PyInstaller in a minimal python environment can get a trivial pandas script standalone `.exe` under 20MB.

[This](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1694#issuecomment-278304957) claims to have gotten one to 15MB using `pyinstaller --onefile --exclude matplotlib --exclude scipy --exclude pandas --exclude numpy --exclude IPython --exclude django`.

So I ran `pyinstaller --onefile --exclude matplotlib --exclude scipy --exclude pandas --exclude numpy --exclude IPython --exclude django TrivialTest.py`, but the resulting `dist\TrivialTest.exe` is still 237MB.

How can I whittle PyInstaller executables to a reasonable size?

E.g.:

- Is there a way I can figure out what PyInstaller is putting in the final `.exe` that I doubt is needed so that I can explicitly exclude it?  If the answer has to do with the contents of `build\xref-trivialtest.html` I think I would be lost: That file alone is over 2.5MB!
- Can I work from the other direction: Figure out independently exactly what is required and then tell PyInstaller to *only* include that?
- Am I just "doing it wrong?"