# long PyInstaller build times when using h5py

Tags: python, pyinstaller, h5py

I have several projects that depend on h5py which I use PyInstaller to build into executables.

It works just fine, but it takes a problematically long time to build an executable as soon as I include h5py.

Below are the logs to build the same "hello world" script into an executable with and without h5py.

**Without: 18seconds**

**With: 713seconds**

Without:

```
(venv) C:\sandbox\test>python -m PyInstaller test_build_time.py
1648 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4.dev0
1648 INFO: Python: 3.6.3
1650 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
1663 INFO: wrote C:\sandbox\test\test_build_time.spec
1685 INFO: UPX is not available.
1693 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\sandbox\\\test']
1694 INFO: checking Analysis
1695 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
1695 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1707 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
1735 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
13871 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
13876 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\sandbox\venv\Scripts\python.exe
13899 WARNING: skipping api-ms-win
14262 INFO: Caching module hooks...
14275 INFO: Analyzing C:\sandbox\test\test_build_time.py
14283 INFO: Loading module hooks...
14283 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-clr.py"...
14316 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
14586 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
14589 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
15291 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
15350 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
15361 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
15782 INFO: Looking for eggs
15783 INFO: Using Python library C:\sandbox\venv\Scripts\python36.dll
15784 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
15815 INFO: Warnings written to C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\warntest_build_time.txt
15937 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\xref-test_build_time.html
15973 INFO: checking PYZ
15974 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
15975 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\out00-PYZ.pyz
17338 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
17371 INFO: checking PKG
17371 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
17372 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
17412 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
17431 INFO: Bootloader C:\sandbox\venv\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
17433 INFO: checking EXE
17435 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
17436 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
17437 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\test_build_time.exe
17469 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
17485 INFO: checking COLLECT
17486 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
17487 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
18317 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

With h5py:

```
(venv) C:\sandbox\test>python -m PyInstaller --hidden-import=h5py test_build_time.py
1816 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4.dev0
1816 INFO: Python: 3.6.3
1818 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
1822 INFO: wrote C:\sandbox\test\test_build_time.spec
1847 INFO: UPX is not available.
1859 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\sandbox\\\test']
1863 INFO: checking Analysis
1871 INFO: Building because hiddenimports changed
1871 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1885 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
1892 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
15299 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'h5py'
22149 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
28709 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
28710 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\sandbox\\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0-py3.6.egg\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
39618 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
71594 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
107118 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
351481 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
351486 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\sandbox\venv\Scripts\python.exe
351511 WARNING: skipping api-ms-win
351816 INFO: Caching module hooks...
351832 INFO: Analyzing C:\sandbox\test\test_build_time.py
351987 INFO: Loading module hooks...
351988 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-babel.py"...
352473 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
352481 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-clr.py"...
352512 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
352516 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-docutils.py"...
356553 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
356887 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-h5py.py"...
356891 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-IPython.py"...
356947 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
356974 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtWidgets from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
356974 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
356978 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
356978 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
356979 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtSvg from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
356979 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
357004 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module IPython.lib.clipboard
357009 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
357051 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
357051 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
357053 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
357054 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
357062 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
357095 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
357096 INFO: Excluding import 'gtk'
357130 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
357162 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
357166 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jinja2.py"...
357225 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jsonschema.py"...
357237 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
357358 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-llvmlite.py"...
357378 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lxml.etree.py"...
357381 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.backends.py"...
359144 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
360513 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
361537 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named 'gtk'
362750 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx'
364105 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
365495 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
366820 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
368044 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
369331 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
370249 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    Cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed.
371634 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
374572 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
380921 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
382016 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
382804 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    Cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed.
383725 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named 'gobject'
384805 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
386474 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
387641 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
388932 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
390001 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
390888 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
391790 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-netCDF4.py"...
392116 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numba.py"...
392132 INFO: Excluding import 'IPython'
392157 INFO:   Removing import of IPython.paths from module numba.caching
392162 INFO:   Removing import of IPython.utils.path from module numba.caching
392172 INFO: Excluding import 'scipy'
392201 INFO:   Removing import of scipy.linalg.cython_blas from module numba.targets.linalg
392201 INFO:   Removing import of scipy.linalg.cython_lapack from module numba.targets.linalg
392217 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
392429 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-patsy.py"...
392432 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
393543 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
393564 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
393565 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
393591 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
393591 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
393597 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
393614 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
393616 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
393636 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
393637 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
393662 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
393680 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
393680 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
393698 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
396659 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pycparser.py"...
397003 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
397004 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pygments.py"...
400525 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
400539 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.Qt.py"...
400542 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
400752 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
402105 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.py"...
402353 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py"...
402354 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
402356 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytest.py"...
404118 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
406214 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
406551 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
408590 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-requests.py"...
408596 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.io.matlab.py"...
408597 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.linalg.py"...
408600 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py"...
408602 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py"...
408603 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
408648 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-shelve.py"...
408650 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sklearn.metrics.cluster.py"...
408882 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_validation" not found!
408883 WARNING: Hidden import "sklearn.utils.sparsetools._graph_tools" not found!
409151 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sphinx.py"...
418260 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlalchemy.py"...
418747 INFO:   Found 3 sqlalchemy hidden imports
418751 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
418753 WARNING: Hidden import "sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func" not found!
418778 INFO: Excluding import 'sqlalchemy.testing'
418792 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.orm.util
418794 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions from module sqlalchemy.testing
418794 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.testing
418794 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.engines from module sqlalchemy.testing
418796 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertions from module sqlalchemy.testing
418799 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.mock from module sqlalchemy.testing
418800 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing
418803 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.warnings from module sqlalchemy.testing
418804 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing
418806 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertsql from module sqlalchemy.testing
418809 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.engines from module sqlalchemy.testing.util
418811 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.util
418812 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.util
418814 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertions from module sqlalchemy.testing.warnings
418816 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.warnings
418817 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.config
418818 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions
418820 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions
418821 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.exclusions from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
418822 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
418825 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.mock from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
418826 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
418833 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
418834 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertsql from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertions
418834 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.mock
418835 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.assertsql
418836 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.util from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
418837 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.assertions from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
418838 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing.config from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
418841 INFO:   Removing import of sqlalchemy.testing from module sqlalchemy.testing.engines
418847 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
419111 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
419113 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-tables.py"...
419115 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
419494 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
419496 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
419497 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
419499 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-zmq.py"...
429662 WARNING: Hidden import "or" not found!
429667 WARNING: Hidden import "_cffi_ext.c" not found!
429672 WARNING: Hidden import "C1083:" not found!
429676 WARNING: Hidden import "fatal" not found!
429681 WARNING: Hidden import "c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(213):" not found!
429686 WARNING: Hidden import "file:" not found!
429690 WARNING: Hidden import "Cannot" not found!
430007 WARNING: Hidden import "directory" not found!
430010 WARNING: Hidden import "file" not found!
430015 WARNING: Hidden import "'sys/un.h':" not found!
430021 WARNING: Hidden import "such" not found!
430427 WARNING: Hidden import "open" not found!
430432 WARNING: Hidden import "No" not found!
430438 WARNING: Hidden import "error" not found!
430454 INFO: Excluding import 'zmq.libzmq'
430471 INFO:   Removing import of zmq.libzmq from module zmq
430475 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
430959 INFO: checking Tree
430959 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
430961 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
431173 INFO: checking Tree
431177 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
431177 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
431291 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py"...
432129 INFO: checking Tree
432129 INFO: Building Tree because out02-Tree.toc is non existent
432130 INFO: Building Tree out02-Tree.toc
432192 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
432398 WARNING: Ignoring /usr/lib/libc.dylib imported from c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\monotonic.py - ctypes imports are only supported using bare filenames
433022 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
433107 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
433113 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
433117 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
433123 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
433129 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
433140 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
433147 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
433158 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
433415 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
436198 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\vccorlib140.dll
438088 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-winrt-error-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\vccorlib140.dll
440082 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\vccorlib140.dll
485663 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\devices\monitoredqueue.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
488892 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\utils.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
490687 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_device.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
492609 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\message.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
494442 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\socket.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
496364 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\error.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
498298 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_poll.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
500093 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_version.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
501921 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp36-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\python\winpython-64bit-3.6.3.0qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\context.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
509757 INFO: Looking for eggs
509757 INFO: Using Python library C:\sandbox\venv\Scripts\python36.dll
509759 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
509916 INFO: Warnings written to C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\warntest_build_time.txt
513928 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\xref-test_build_time.html
514694 INFO: checking PYZ
514699 INFO: Building because toc changed
514700 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\out00-PYZ.pyz
537798 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
538267 INFO: checking PKG
538268 INFO: Building because toc changed
538269 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
538421 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
538426 INFO: Bootloader C:\sandbox\venv\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
538426 INFO: checking EXE
538430 INFO: Building because toc changed
538430 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
538433 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\sandbox\test\build\test_build_time\test_build_time.exe
538520 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
538541 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "C:\sandbox\test\dist\test_build_time" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/n)y
586293 INFO: Removing dir C:\sandbox\test\dist\test_build_time
586315 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
597846 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py._errors.pyd
597860 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
598036 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py._conv.pyd
598056 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
598204 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5z.pyd
598207 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
598416 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5a.pyd
598439 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
598583 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5d.pyd
598598 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
598773 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5ds.pyd
598779 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
598934 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5f.pyd
598943 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
599101 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5fd.pyd
599108 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
599322 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5g.pyd
599333 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
599476 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5r.pyd
599477 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
599618 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5s.pyd
599623 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
599727 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5t.pyd
599729 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
599853 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5p.pyd
599855 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
599977 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5.pyd
599978 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
600094 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py._objects.pyd
600096 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
611245 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5i.pyd
611256 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
611405 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5o.pyd
611413 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
611556 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5l.pyd
611560 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
611693 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.h5ac.pyd
611699 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
611839 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.defs.pyd
611841 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
611973 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py.utils.pyd
611982 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
612097 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\h5py._proxy.pyd
612099 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
612787 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\hdf5.dll
612789 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
613877 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py36_64bit\hdf5_hl.dll
613894 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
713098 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully.
```

a large portion of the time is spent on the following two lines:

```
71594 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
107118 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
351481 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
```

Is there any way I can speed that up?

So much of the time seems spent analyzing the libraries that never change. Is there any way to force PyInstaller to reuse previous anylysis?

Comment: The second log mentions IPython several times. h5py has an entirely optional [IPython tab-completion integration module](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/h5py/ipy_completer.py). I guess that Pyinstaller is noticing that and then bringing in IPython and a bunch of stuff that IPython imports as well. The perils of detecting dependencies by looking at import statements.

Comment: @ThomasK I could just kiss you for this solution!  And for anyone looking at this trying to exclude a module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890159/python-excluding-modules-pyinstaller/17595149#17595149