# How to prevent pyinstaller from adding unneccessary and unrelated files?

Tags: pyinstaller

I was puzzled to see that some files and folders are actually ending up in the `pyinstaller` generated dist folder. For example, the `.git` in my project root is ending up as `dist/Script/mpl-data/.git` together with other files from the root directory. Any idea how to prevent that?

The specfile I am using looks like this:

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['..\\scripts\\scipt.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\..\\scripts'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[...],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn'],  
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['**/*.git', '**/__cache__', '**/dist', '**/build', '**/InnoSetup'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
             
 exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Script',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='Script')
```

I tried to add the directory names to exclude, but that does not work.

The way I am using pyinstaller is from the root directory of my package.

```
|-package/__init__.py
|   |...
|-specfiles/pyinstaller_specfile.spec
|-scripts/mainscript.py
|-hooks/...
|-setup.py
|...
```

And I call

```
pyinstaller --onedir --noconfirm specfiles\pyinstaller_specfile.spec --additional-hooks-dir=hooks
```

Comment: Did you try searching the PyInstaller documentation - there’s all the details of how to do this there

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890159/python-excluding-modules-pyinstaller

Comment: Yes, that I did first, but the info in the docs did not help.

Answer (score 0):

What helped was to change the directory from which I ran the pyinstaller.

Instead of the root directory and calling

```
pyinstaller --onedir --noconfirm specfiles\pyinstaller_specfile.spec --additional-hooks-dir=hooks
```

I changed into `specfiles` and called:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --noconfirm pyinstaller_specfile.spec --additional-hooks-dir=hooks
```

This changed the location of the dist folder (into specfiles), but prevented all those unneeded files being imported.

**Update**: Updating to the latest version of pyinstaller worked even better.